# Publish a separate project as PreBuildEvent

Tags: .net, build

I need to publish a separate project (**project-B**) on build in order to create it's DLLs which I need in my main project (**project-A**) in order to run. As to why I am doing doing - I'm designing a specific tool that needs references to other services (using git submodules) in order to operate and has to run in a container. However due to poor design on some of those services I need to reference **actual ASP.NET we**b projects. This then fails during **project-A** publish in docker, because there are duplicate files such as `appsettings.json` from **project-B**. To solve this I've referenced only the necessary dlls from project-B and now I want to automate the build process to make sure they are always there.

Project structure is like this:

```
-submodules
--ProjectB
---src
----ProjectB
-----ProjectB.csproj
-src
--.sln
--ProjectA
---ProjectA.csproj
```

I'd like to keep the submodules at root so I tried to resolve the path like this:

```
dotnet publish "../../submodules/B/src/ProjectB"
```

but it doesn't work. I've tried the following assumptions as to which is the active directory at evaluation time:

- ProjectA
- src
- root

But none worked. I also tried some VS [Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-170&redirectedfrom=MSDN), but I didn't find any useful ones.

I suspect this will be easier to solve if `submodules` dir is nested under `ProjectA` or `/src`, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. Also I want to mention that I need a **relative path solution**.

This mostly raises two questions:

- Can I solve it without moving the submodules?
- What is the active directory during build time and why it isn't something more intuitive?